# SFSpeechRecognizer is not available

Tags: swift, speech-recognition, ios10

I've downloaded the sample code SpeakToMe at: 
https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/samplecode/SpeakToMe/Introduction/Intro.html 
Run it on the device and start recording but receiving no response. After a little debug I see the speechRecognizer.isAvailable is false. But sometimes it still available and work normally. I've checked internet connection as recommendation at https://developer.apple.com/reference/speech/sfspeechrecognizer/1649885-isavailable 
What can I do in this situation?

Thank you

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Either Siri or Dictation needs to be enabled in Settings:

- iOS 10: Settings -> Siri -> Turn ON
- iOS 11: Settings -> Press
  Home/Side Button for Siri -> Turn ON

or

- Settings -> General -> Keyboard -> Enable Dictation -> Turn ON

Comment: Enabling and configuring siri worked for me on ios 13

Answer (score 2):

Eddie's answer is a bit off now in iOS 11, with Siri settings being changed.

> From Settings, select **Siri & Search:**

[image]

> Then choose one or both of these options:

[image]

Comment: Apple rejected my app because they didn't have this on... wow